# Convert int to date

Tags: python, date, datetime

I'm trying to convert yyyy/mm/dd to dd/mm/yyyy, from integer inputs.

When i've changed the pattern inside the parethesis from `datetime.date(year, month, day)`, to `datetime.date(day, month, year)`, it returns an *Value error*.

```
def acc_expiration():
    year = int(input('YEAR: '))
    month = int(input('MONTH: '))
    day = int(input('DAY: '))
    exp_date = datetime.date(day, month, year)
    return exp_date

ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

Comment: what input did you give it? if you gave for example MONTH: 2 and DAYS: 29 this would raise an error as February has only 28 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects):

> class datetime.date(year, month, day)

This means you need to put the arguments in the right position, doesn't matter how you want to print it later.

This should work:

```py
def acc_expiration():
    year = int(input('YEAR: '))
    month = int(input('MONTH: '))
    day = int(input('DAY: '))
    exp_date = datetime.date(year, month, day)
    return exp_date
```

Now let's print it formatted in dd/mm/yyyy:

```
d = acc_expiration()
f = d.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
print(f) # prints it formatted dd/mm/yyyy
```

Your value error is because you are giving a year integer (integer bigger than 31) to the day argument, and for the year you are giving the day integer.

Comment: @LuizGodoy Please select the answer as the correct one then, please, good to know i helped

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the object from its presentation.

Look at the Python docs for Datetime ([here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html))

1. The correct sequence for datetime.date is [class datetime.datetime(year, month, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, microsecond[, tzinfo]]]]])](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects)
2. Once you have a datetime object, you can format the output of it in a variety of ways to suit your needs.

Does that help?

Comment: Yeah, i think that i can fix only the output. Thank you!